# Multiple Ajax call in same page

Tags: ajax

I used ajax call for vote and unvote for same choice. If the user clicks for the first time the image will replaced by voted and again if the user click the same choice for unvote, the image will replace as vote. When click that image it will take two variables and go to ajax page.

But in my page the first time it works fine. But second time the user clicks for unvote functionality, it is not working and not replacing the image as unvote.

Can anyone help me for this problem.

http://domian.com/mysite/pollpage.php?id=7&mview=6

This is the URL. After login with fb or twitter we can vote for the choices

Codings in main page

```
$('.vote').click(function() {
    alert("=====");
    var valueid=$(this).attr("alt");
    alert(valueid);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "voteajax.php",
        data: "votebtn="+valueid+""
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        var received_data=msg.trim();
        if(received_data=='0')
        {
            alert('Please sign in to vote!');
        }
        else
        {
            alert('received data'+received_data);
            gg2=received_data.split("/");
            var x=gg2[0];
            var no_of_vote=gg2[1];
            $('#totalnoofvotespan').html(no_of_vote);
            //$('#totalnoofvotespan').attr('innerHTML', 'newhtml');
            $('.vote').attr('src', 'images/voteblue.jpg');
            $('#vote'+x).attr('src', 'images/voted.jpg');
           window.location='<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>';
        }
    });
});
```

Codings for that voteajax page

```
$pollid=$ex[0];

$choiceid=$ex[1];

$sel_dup1=$jeob->SqlQuery("select * from je_user_vote where user_id='$userid' AND poll_id='$pollid' AND choice_id='$choiceid'");

$rr=mysql_num_rows($sel_dup1);


    if($rr=="0") 
    {

            $query=mysql_query("update je_user_vote set user_id ='$userid',poll_id='$pollid',choice_id ='$choiceid',datetime_voted='$date' where user_id ='$userid' AND poll_id='$pollid' ");
                    $query_fbfr = mysql_query("update je_fbvote_count set fbuser_id ='$userid',fbpoll_id='$pollid',fbchoice_id ='$choiceid',datetime_created='$date' where fbuser_id ='$userid' AND fbpoll_id='$pollid' ");

    }
    else
    {
        //echo "delete from je_user_vote where user_id='$userid' AND poll_id='$pollid' AND choice_id='$choiceid'";
        mysql_query("delete from je_user_vote where user_id='$userid' AND poll_id='$pollid' AND choice_id='$choiceid'");
            mysql_query("delete from je_fbvote_count where fbuser_id='$userid' AND fbpoll_id='$pollid' AND fbchoice_id='$choiceid'");
    }
```

The codings are in ajax in which i write to update and delete the votes
In the above coding, the update is working fine, but when try to delete from the main page it is not executing the delete query

Comment: Posting some code would make this question answerable.

Comment: ofcourse. I will post the codings also.

Comment: Is the codings clear to you. The first one is for main page and the second one for ajax page.

Comment: http://domian.com/mysite/pollpage.php?id=7&mview=6
is not working

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't unvote. It seems that you don't have that logic in your code. There's only voted functionalty:

```
$('#vote'+x).attr('src', 'images/voted.jpg');
```

There's nothing like:

```
if (voted) {
     $('#vote'+x).remove();
     voted = false;
}
```

I'd vote for `'; drop table je_user_vote`, by the way.

Answer (score -1):

```
**Index.php**

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<!-- This is a pagination script using Jquery, Ajax and PHP
     The enhancements done in this script pagination with first,last, previous, next buttons -->

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Pagination with Jquery, Ajax, PHP</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="pagingstyle.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script_div.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="validate.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div style="margin-top:10px;"> 
      <blockquote>&nbsp;</blockquote>
<!--    <iframe src="http://onlinewebapplication.com/ads.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="126px" width="100%"></iframe></div> -->
</div> 
<div align="center" style="font-size:24px;color:#cc0000;font-weight:bold">Pagination with jquery, Ajax and PHP</div>
<select id="user">
<option value="-1">select..</option>
<option value="activate">activate</option>
<option value="deactivate">deactivate</option>
</select>

        <div id="container" class="box">
            <div class="data" class="box"></div>
            <div class="pagination" class="box"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="container2">
            <div class="data2"></div>
            <div class="pagination2"></div>
        </div>
<!--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
        <select id="car">
<option value="">select..</option>
<option value="white">white</option>
<option value="red">red</option>
<option value="black">black</option>
<option value="silver">silver</option>
</select>
        <div id="container1"  class="box1">
            <div class="data1"  class="box1"></div>
            <div class="pagination1"  class="box1"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="container3">
            <div class="data3"></div>
            <div class="pagination3"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
**`userdata.php`**
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
if($_POST['page'])
{
$page = $_POST['page'];
$cur_page = $page;
$page -= 1;
$per_page = 1;
$previous_btn = true;
$next_btn = true;
$first_btn = true;
$last_btn = true;
$start = $page * $per_page;
include "config.php";
$query_pag_data = "SELECT * from users LIMIT $start, $per_page";
$result_pag_data = mysql_query($query_pag_data) or die('MySql Error' . mysql_error());
$msg = "";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_pag_data)) {
$htmlmsg=htmlentities($row['name']);
    $msg .= "<li><b>" . $row['id'] . "</b> " . $htmlmsg . "</li>";
}
$msg = "<div class='data'><ul>" . $msg . "</ul></div>"; // Content for Data
/* --------------------------------------------- */
$query_pag_num = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM users";
$result_pag_num = mysql_query($query_pag_num);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result_pag_num);
$count = $row['count'];
$no_of_paginations = ceil($count / $per_page);

/*---------------Calculating the starting and endign values for the loop----------------------------------- */
if ($cur_page >= 7) {
    $start_loop = $cur_page - 3;
    if ($no_of_paginations > $cur_page + 3)
        $end_loop = $cur_page + 3;
    else if ($cur_page <= $no_of_paginations && $cur_page > $no_of_paginations - 6) {
        $start_loop = $no_of_paginations - 6;
        $end_loop = $no_of_paginations;
    } else {
        $end_loop = $no_of_paginations;
    }
} else {
    $start_loop = 1;
    if ($no_of_paginations > 7)
        $end_loop = 7;
    else
        $end_loop = $no_of_paginations;
}
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
$msg .= "<div class='pagination'><ul>";

// FOR ENABLING THE FIRST BUTTON
if ($first_btn && $cur_page > 1) {
    $msg .= "<li p='1' class='active'>first</li>";
} else if ($first_btn) {
    $msg .= "<li p='1' class='inactive'>first</li>";
}

// FOR ENABLING THE PREVIOUS BUTTON
if ($previous_btn && $cur_page > 1) {
    $pre = $cur_page - 1;
    $msg .= "<li p='$pre' class='active'>Previous</li>";
} else if ($previous_btn) {
    $msg .= "<li class='inactive'>Previous</li>";
}
for ($i = $start_loop; $i <= $end_loop; $i++) {

    if ($cur_page == $i)
        $msg .= "<li p='$i' style='color:#fff;background-color:#006699;' class='active'>{$i}</li>";
    else
        $msg .= "<li p='$i' class='active'>{$i}</li>";
}

// TO ENABLE THE NEXT BUTTON
if ($next_btn && $cur_page < $no_of_paginations) {
    $nex = $cur_page + 1;
    $msg .= "<li p='$nex' class='active'>Next</li>";
} else if ($next_btn) {
    $msg .= "<li class='inactive'>Next</li>";
}

// TO ENABLE THE END BUTTON
if ($last_btn && $cur_page < $no_of_paginations) {
    $msg .= "<li p='$no_of_paginations' class='active'>Last</li>";
} else if ($last_btn) {
    $msg .= "<li p='$no_of_paginations' class='inactive'>Last</li>";
}
$goto = "<input type='text' class='goto' size='1' style='margin-top:-1px;margin-left:60px;'/><input type='button' id='go_btn' class='go_button' value='Go'/>";
$total_string = "<span class='total' a='$no_of_paginations'>Page <b>" . $cur_page . "</b> of <b>$no_of_paginations</b></span>";
$msg = $msg . "</ul>" . $goto . $total_string . "</div>";  // Content for pagination
echo $msg;
}

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
**`cardata.php`**
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
if($_POST['page'])
{
$page = $_POST['page'];
$cur_page = $page;
$page -= 1;
$per_page = 1;
$previous_btn = true;
$next_btn = true;
$first_btn = true;
$last_btn = true;
$start = $page * $per_page;
include "config.php";
$query_pag_data = "SELECT * from cars LIMIT $start, $per_page";
$result_pag_data = mysql_query($query_pag_data) or die('MySql Error' . mysql_error());
$msg = "";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_pag_data)) {
$htmlmsg=htmlentities($row['car_name']);
    $msg .= "<li><b>" . $row['id'] . "</b> " . $htmlmsg . "</li>";
}
$msg = "<div class='data1'><ul>" . $msg . "</ul></div>"; // Content for Data
/* --------------------------------------------- */
$query_pag_num = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM cars";
$result_pag_num = mysql_query($query_pag_num);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result_pag_num);
$count = $row['count'];
$no_of_paginations = ceil($count / $per_page);

/*---------------Calculating the starting and endign values for the loop----------------------------------- */
if ($cur_page >= 7) {
    $start_loop = $cur_page - 3;
    if ($no_of_paginations > $cur_page + 3)
        $end_loop = $cur_page + 3;
    else if ($cur_page <= $no_of_paginations && $cur_page > $no_of_paginations - 6) {
        $start_loop = $no_of_paginations - 6;
        $end_loop = $no_of_paginations;
    } else {
        $end_loop = $no_of_paginations;
    }
} else {
    $start_loop = 1;
    if ($no_of_paginations > 7)
        $end_loop = 7;
    else
        $end_loop = $no_of_paginations;
}
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
$msg .= "<div class='pagination1'><ul>";

// FOR ENABLING THE FIRST BUTTON
if ($first_btn && $cur_page > 1) {
    $msg .= "<li p='1' class='active'>first</li>";
} else if ($first_btn) {
    $msg .= "<li p='1' class='inactive'>first</li>";
}

// FOR ENABLING THE PREVIOUS BUTTON
if ($previous_btn && $cur_page > 1) {
    $pre = $cur_page - 1;
    $msg .= "<li p='$pre' class='active'>Previous</li>";
} else if ($previous_btn) {
    $msg .= "<li class='inactive'>Previous</li>";
}
for ($k = $start_loop; $k <= $end_loop; $k++) {

    if ($cur_page == $k)
        $msg .= "<li p='$k' style='color:#fff;background-color:#006699;' class='inactive'>{$k}</li>";
    else
        $msg .= "<li p='$k' class='active'>{$k}</li>";
}

// TO ENABLE THE NEXT BUTTON
if ($next_btn && $cur_page < $no_of_paginations) {
    $nex = $cur_page + 1;
    $msg .= "<li p='$nex' class='active'>Next</li>";
} else if ($next_btn) {
    $msg .= "<li class='inactive'>Next</li>";
}

// TO ENABLE THE END BUTTON
if ($last_btn && $cur_page < $no_of_paginations) {
    $msg .= "<li p='$no_of_paginations' class='active'>Last</li>";
} else if ($last_btn) {
    $msg .= "<li p='$no_of_paginations' class='inactive'>Last</li>";
}
$goto = "<input type='text' class='goto1' size='1' style='margin-top:-1px;margin-left:60px;'/><input type='button' id='go_btn1' class='go_button' value='Go'/>";
$total_string = "<span class='total1' a1='$no_of_paginations'>Page <b>" . $cur_page . "</b> of <b>$no_of_paginations</b></span>";
$msg = $msg . "</ul>" . $goto . $total_string . "</div>";  // Content for pagination
echo $msg;
}
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
**`userstatus.php`**

<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
if($_POST['page'])
{
    $q=$_POST['q'];
    //echo "value:".$q;
$page = $_POST['page'];
$cur_page = $page;
$page -= 1;
$per_page = 1;
$previous_btn = true;
$next_btn = true;
$first_btn = true;
$last_btn = true;
$start = $page * $per_page;
include "config.php";
$query_pag_data = "SELECT * from users where status='$q' LIMIT $start, $per_page";
$result_pag_data = mysql_query($query_pag_data) or die('MySql Error' . mysql_error());
$msg = "";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_pag_data)) {
$htmlmsg=htmlentities($row['name']);
    $msg .= "<li><b>" . $row['id'] . "</b> " . $htmlmsg . "</li>";
}
$msg = "<div class='data2'><ul>" . $msg . "</ul></div>"; // Content for Data
/* --------------------------------------------- */
$query_pag_num = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM users where status='$q'";
$result_pag_num = mysql_query($query_pag_num);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result_pag_num);
$count = $row['count'];
$no_of_paginations = ceil($count / $per_page);

/*---------------Calculating the starting and endign values for the loop----------------------------------- */
if ($cur_page >= 7) {
    $start_loop = $cur_page - 3;
    if ($no_of_paginations > $cur_page + 3)
        $end_loop = $cur_page + 3;
    else if ($cur_page <= $no_of_paginations && $cur_page > $no_of_paginations - 6) {
        $start_loop = $no_of_paginations - 6;
        $end_loop = $no_of_paginations;
    } else {
        $end_loop = $no_of_paginations;
    }
} else {
    $start_loop = 1;
    if ($no_of_paginations > 7)
        $end_loop = 7;
    else
        $end_loop = $no_of_paginations;
}
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
$msg .= "<div class='pagination2'><ul>";

// FOR ENABLING THE FIRST BUTTON
if ($first_btn && $cur_page > 1) {
    $msg .= "<li p='1' class='active'>First</li>";
} else if ($first_btn) {
    $msg .= "<li p='1' class='inactive'>First</li>";
}

// FOR ENABLING THE PREVIOUS BUTTON
if ($previous_btn && $cur_page > 1) {
    $pre = $cur_page - 1;
    $msg .= "<li p='$pre' class='active'>Previous</li>";
} else if ($previous_btn) {
    $msg .= "<li class='inactive'>Previous</li>";
}
for ($i = $start_loop; $i <= $end_loop; $i++) {

    if ($cur_page == $i)
        $msg .= "<li p='$i' style='color:#fff;background-color:#006699;' class='active'>{$i}</li>";
    else
        $msg .= "<li p='$i' class='active'>{$i}</li>";
}

// TO ENABLE THE NEXT BUTTON
if ($next_btn && $cur_page < $no_of_paginations) {
    $nex = $cur_page + 1;
    $msg .= "<li p='$nex' class='active'>Next</li>";
} else if ($next_btn) {
    $msg .= "<li class='inactive'>Next</li>";
}

// TO ENABLE THE END BUTTON
if ($last_btn && $cur_page < $no_of_paginations) {
    $msg .= "<li p='$no_of_paginations' class='active'>Last</li>";
} else if ($last_btn) {
    $msg .= "<li p='$no_of_paginations' class='inactive'>Last</li>";
}
$goto = "<input type='text' class='goto2' size='1' style='margin-top:-1px;margin-left:60px;'/><input type='button' id='go_btn2' class='go_button' value='Go'/>";
$total_string = "<span class='total2' a2='$no_of_paginations'>Page <b>" . $cur_page . "</b> of <b>$no_of_paginations</b></span>";
$msg = $msg . "</ul>" . $goto . $total_string . "</div>";  // Content for pagination
echo $msg;
}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
**`carcolor.php`**
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
if($_POST['page'])
{
    $q=$_POST['q'];
    //echo "value:".$q;
$page = $_POST['page'];
$cur_page = $page;
$page -= 1;
$per_page = 1;
$previous_btn = true;
$next_btn = true;
$first_btn = true;
$last_btn = true;
$start = $page * $per_page;
include "config.php";
$query_pag_data = "SELECT * from cars where color='$q' LIMIT $start, $per_page";
$result_pag_data = mysql_query($query_pag_data) or die('MySql Error' . mysql_error());
$msg = "";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_pag_data)) {
$htmlmsg=htmlentities($row['car_name']);
    $msg .= "<li><b>" . $row['id'] . "</b> " . $htmlmsg . "</li>";
}
$msg = "<div class='data3'><ul>" . $msg . "</ul></div>"; // Content for Data
/* --------------------------------------------- */
$query_pag_num = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM cars where color='$q'";
$result_pag_num = mysql_query($query_pag_num);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result_pag_num);
$count = $row['count'];
$no_of_paginations = ceil($count / $per_page);

/*---------------Calculating the starting and endign values for the loop----------------------------------- */
if ($cur_page >= 7) {
    $start_loop = $cur_page - 3;
    if ($no_of_paginations > $cur_page + 3)
        $end_loop = $cur_page + 3;
    else if ($cur_page <= $no_of_paginations && $cur_page > $no_of_paginations - 6) {
        $start_loop = $no_of_paginations - 6;
        $end_loop = $no_of_paginations;
    } else {
        $end_loop = $no_of_paginations;
    }
} else {
    $start_loop = 1;
    if ($no_of_paginations > 7)
        $end_loop = 7;
    else
        $end_loop = $no_of_paginations;
}
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
$msg .= "<div class='pagination3'><ul>";

// FOR ENABLING THE FIRST BUTTON
if ($first_btn && $cur_page > 1) {
    $msg .= "<li p='1' class='active'>First</li>";
} else if ($first_btn) {
    $msg .= "<li p='1' class='inactive'>First</li>";
}

// FOR ENABLING THE PREVIOUS BUTTON
if ($previous_btn && $cur_page > 1) {
    $pre = $cur_page - 1;
    $msg .= "<li p='$pre' class='active'>Previous</li>";
} else if ($previous_btn) {
    $msg .= "<li class='inactive'>Previous</li>";
}
for ($i = $start_loop; $i <= $end_loop; $i++) {

    if ($cur_page == $i)
        $msg .= "<li p='$i' style='color:#fff;background-color:#006699;' class='active'>{$i}</li>";
    else
        $msg .= "<li p='$i' class='active'>{$i}</li>";
}

// TO ENABLE THE NEXT BUTTON
if ($next_btn && $cur_page < $no_of_paginations) {
    $nex = $cur_page + 1;
    $msg .= "<li p='$nex' class='active'>Next</li>";
} else if ($next_btn) {
    $msg .= "<li class='inactive'>Next</li>";
}

// TO ENABLE THE END BUTTON
if ($last_btn && $cur_page < $no_of_paginations) {
    $msg .= "<li p='$no_of_paginations' class='active'>Last</li>";
} else if ($last_btn) {
    $msg .= "<li p='$no_of_paginations' class='inactive'>Last</li>";
}
$goto = "<input type='text' class='goto3' size='1' style='margin-top:-1px;margin-left:60px;'/><input type='button' id='go_btn3' class='go_button' value='Go'/>";
$total_string = "<span class='total3' a3='$no_of_paginations'>Page <b>" . $cur_page . "</b> of <b>$no_of_paginations</b></span>";
$msg = $msg . "</ul>" . $goto . $total_string . "</div>";  // Content for pagination
echo $msg;
}
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
config.php
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("error:".mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db("test2",$con);
?>
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
script_div.js

            $(document).ready(function(){       
                function loadData(page){                 
                    $.ajax
                    ({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "userdata.php",
                        data: "page="+page,
                        success: function(msg)
                        {
                            //alert("I AM FIRST:"+msg);
                            $("#container").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                            {
                                $("#container").html(msg);
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
                loadData(1);  // For first time page load default results
                $('#container .pagination li.active').live('click',function(){
                    var page = $(this).attr('p');
                    loadData(page);

                });           
                $('#go_btn').live('click',function(){
                    var page = parseInt($('.goto').val());
                    var no_of_pages = parseInt($('.total').attr('a'));
                    if(page != 0 && page <= no_of_pages){
                        loadData(page);
                    }else{
                        alert('Enter a PAGE between 1 and '+no_of_pages);
                        $('.goto').val("").focus();
                        return false;
                    }

                });
                $('#user').change(function(){
                    var location = $(this).val();
                    /* don't do anything if blank option selected*/
                     if( location !=''){
                         $('.box').hide();
                         //$('#'+location).show();
                     }
                     else if(location=="-1")
                         {
                         $('.box').show();
                         }

                });
            });

//<!----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
//<!--user data with filtration-->

                $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#user').change(function(){
                    dis=$(this).val();
                    function loadData(page){  
                        //alert(dis);               
                        $.ajax
                        ({

                            type: "POST",
                            url: "userstatus.php",
                            data: {page:page,
                                q:dis},
                            success: function(msg1)
                            {
                                //alert("I AM MESSAGE 1"+msg1);
                                $("#container2").ajaxComplete(function(event1, request1, settings1)
                                {

                                    $("#container2").html(msg1);
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    loadData(1);  // For first time page load default results
                    $('#container2 .pagination2 li.active').live('click',function(){
                        var page = $(this).attr('p');
                        loadData(page);

                    });           
                    $('#go_btn2').live('click',function(){
                        var page = parseInt($('.goto2').val());
                        var no_of_pages = parseInt($('.total2').attr('a2'));
                        if(page != 0 && page <= no_of_pages){
                            loadData(page);
                        }else{
                            alert('Enter a PAGE between 1 and '+no_of_pages);
                            $('.goto2').val("").focus();
                            return false;
                        }

                    });
                    });   
            });

//<!---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
//<!--car data-->

                $(document).ready(function(){       
                    function loadData(page){                 
                        $.ajax
                        ({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "cardata.php",
                            data: "page="+page,
                            success: function(msg)
                            {
                                //alert("I AM FIRST:"+msg);
                                $("#container1").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                                {
                                    $("#container1").html(msg);
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    loadData(1);  // For first time page load default results
                    $('#container1 .pagination1 li.active').live('click',function(){
                        var page = $(this).attr('p');
                        loadData(page);

                    });           
                    $('#go_btn1').live('click',function(){
                        var page = parseInt($('.goto1').val());
                        var no_of_pages = parseInt($('.total1').attr('a1'));
                        if(page != 0 && page <= no_of_pages){
                            loadData(page);
                        }else{
                            alert('Enter a PAGE between 1 and '+no_of_pages);
                            $('.goto1').val("").focus();
                            return false;
                        }

                    });
                    $('#car').change(function(){
                        var location = $(this).val();
                        /* don't do anything if blank option selected*/
                         if( location !=''){
                             $('.box1').hide();
                             //$('#'+location).show();
                         }

                    });
                });
//<!----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
//<!--car data with filtration-->

                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#car').change(function(){
                        dis1=$(this).val();
                        function loadData(page){          
                            $.ajax
                            ({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "carcolor.php",
                                data: {page:page,
                                    q:dis1},
                                success: function(msg3)
                                {
                                    //alert("I AM MESSAGE 1"+msg1);
                                    $("#container3").ajaxComplete(function(event3, request3, settings3)
                                    {

                                        $("#container3").html(msg3);
                                    });enter code here
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        loadData(1);  // For first time page load default results
                        $('#container3 .pagination3 li.active').live('click',function(){
                            var page = $(this).attr('p');
                            loadData(page);

                        });           
                        $('#go_btn3').live('click',function(){
                            var page = parseInt($('.goto3').val());
                            var no_of_pages = parseInt($('.total3').attr('a3'));
                            if(page != 0 && page <= no_of_pages){
                                loadData(page);
                            }else{
                                alert('Enter a PAGE between 1 and '+no_of_pages);
                                $('.goto3').val("").focus();
                                return false;
                            }

                        });
                        });   
                });
```